# javax.mail.authenticationfailedexception in Android on Mobile network

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

Apologies if I could not locate the existing thread on this, though I did my search.

I am getting exception javax.mail.authenticationfailedexception when I try to send mail via mobile network, but same code works fine when I enable wifi on my phone.

Also same code also works fine in ADK simulators also, but it is failing only when I enable Mobile data on my phone(provided disabling wifi).

Looks a basic thing though, any idea what I am missing, any permission or other stuff. Did not find anything regarding mobile data in "permission" section.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  The protocol trace might provide additional details about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a coding issue at all.  Your mobile network may introduce a man-in-the-middle, block ports, direct you to a different mail server though split-horizon dns, be blacklisted, or introduce any number of non-code related issues.  I suggest tethering your desktop to your mobile and attempting to run the code on your desktop.  If it turns out to be the mobile network you could always get around it by creating a web-service to perform the intended function and accessing it from your Android device.  You might also want to inspect the source code that throws the javax.mail.authenticationfailed exception for clues if you have access to it.